# How to implement .scrollTo plugin with a dropdown list

Tags: jquery

How to implement `.scrollTo` plugin in a dropdown list? When I choose one option from a dropdown list, it gets the value and shows specific div but how to make this div scroll up instantly after the user chooses the option? I used this plugin already with links a href and this is easy but I have no idea how to implement it with dropdowns.
Here is the html:

```
<select id="miasto">
    <option value="v1">opt1</option>
    <option value="v2">opt1</option>
    <option value="v3">opt1</option>
</select>
```

Divs to be be displayed after selecting an option:

```
<div id="v1" class="schowaj" style="display:none">div1 content</div>
<div id="v2" class="schowaj" style="display:none">div2 content</div>
<div id="v3" class="schowaj" style="display:none">div3 content</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('#miasto').change(function(){
    var divToShow = $('#'+$(this).val());
    $('.schowaj').not(divToShow).hide('slow');
    divToShow.show('slow');
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code into select change event listener:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var divToShow = $('#'+$(this).val());
    $('.schowaj').not(divToShow).hide('slow');
    divToShow.show('slow');

    var offset = divToShow.offset().top;
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 1500);
});
```